# GAE Datastore Load Data Not Working

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a difficulty querying my entities from GAE Datastore. This is my entities :

[image: My entities in datastore]

And this is my code for loading data :

```
    @ApiMethod(name = "getUserPost", path = "getUserPost",
            httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)

    public Posts[] getUserPost(@Named("userEmail") String userEmail, @Named("apikey") String apikey){
       OfyService.ofy().factory().begin();

       Posts[] arr = new Posts[100];
       int ctr = 0;
      //Query<Posts> q = OfyService.ofy().load().type(Posts.class).filter("postUserEmail", userEmail);
      List<Posts> q = OfyService.ofy().load().type(Posts.class).filter("postUserEmail", userEmail).list();
      for (Posts thepost: q) {
          arr[ctr] = thepost;
          ctr++;
      }

      return arr;
    }
```

I can't use Query neither List to get my entities. The `arr` is always null.

Please help me.

Comment: Is `postUserEmail` indexed (`@Index`)?

Comment: tx802 probably has the right answer, but you should include the source code for Posts.class if you want more than just a guess. Also: You should not call begin() in your code (it does nothing as written), and that array manipulation code is really weird. Call `List.toArray()`.

Comment: I added `@Index` to field `postUserEmail` and it works! Thank you @tx802 and @stickfigure